# Cordova Media Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to setup cordova-media-plugin but the media files are not played. The logs say:

```
THREAD WARNING: ['Media'] took '22.759277' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Found resource '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxx/MySound.app/www/res/snd/_beep.wav' in the web folder.
Playing audio sample 'res/snd/_beep.wav' 
Playing stream with AVPlayer & custom rate
```

So, only a warning but no sound at all. I tried wav and mp3 files.

I added the plugin by:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
```

I also tried to uninstall and reinstall the plugin

I initiate the sound call like:

```
var successFn = function(){App.logDebug("played sound")},
    errorFn = function(error){App.logError("playing sound failed",error)};

var media = new Media("res/snd/_beep.wav", successFn, errorFn);
media.play();
```

The code runs without problems but the successFn is never called. I tried everything and found nothing which could solve this problem.

thx for any hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an iOS Bug with version cordova 4.x and media plugin 2.2.0:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10849